# Symfony4 firewalls logout

Tags: security, logout, symfony4

Give me some clues to add a **logoutlistener** in security.yaml of **symfony4**

**Error:**
The service "security.logout_listener.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "some.service.id".

In security.yaml

```
logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: false
                delete_cookies:
                    a: { path: null, domain: null }
                    b: { path: null, domain: null }
                handlers: [some.service.id]
```

Comment: What path i should give to logout button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add these commands**

**In security.yaml**

```
logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
```

**In controller**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {

    }
```

**In logout button**

```
<a class="text-muted" href="{{ path('logout') }}">logout </a>
```

Comment: No need of cookies and handlers

Answer (score -1):

this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out) can help you , so just don't forget to add your to add controller to have route /logout, and after the firewall can handle automatically your logout when you add this route in your config parameter